# Dynamically linking html pages with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

This is the code to store five images for an HTML page
and then the function is used
to display those five images one at a time.

This code works and one can scroll through the five images.

My question is whether it is possible to direct to different HTML page on the basis of image shown at a particular time

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var curImage = 0;
    var cImages = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg'];

    function townHousePics(direction) {
        if (direction == 'next') {
            curImage++;
            if (curImage == 5) {
                curImage = 0;
            }        
        } 
        else 
        {
            curImage--;
            // even reset the counter here when
            // its getting 0
        }
        document.images[0].src = cImages[curImage];
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You mean you want to have a url associated with each image, and when the image is clicked, the page at the given url is loaded?

Comment: Wrap you `image` in `anchor` tag with `href` of  the html page where you want to redirect!... and your work is done.

Comment: @ Jonathan M, Yes SIR,
Kindly tell me how can those images be linked to different pages...
@ Murtaza SIR, kindly let me know how can this be done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## html setup

```
<a href='' id='my-anchor-name'><img id='my-image-name' src=''/></a>
```

## javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var curImage = 0;
    var cImages = [{aHref:'target1.html',imgHref:'1.jpg'},{aHref:'target2.html',imgHref:'2.jpg'},
{aHref:'target3.html',imgHref:'3.jpg'},
{aHref:'target4.html',imgHref:'4.jpg'},
{aHref:'target5.html',imgHref:'5.jpg'}
];
         function townHousePics(direction) {
                     if (direction == 'next') {
                         curImage = (curImage++)%cImages.length ;
                      else {
                         curimage = (curImage--)%cImages.length;
                     }
                     var img = document.getElementById('my-image-name');
                     var anchor = document.getElementById('my-anchor-name')
                     img.src = cImages[curImage].imgHref;
                     anchor.href = cImage[curImage].aHref;
             }
</script>
```

Comment: I changed cImages into a json object to allow more freedom in the 'target' urls for the enclosing anchor tag.   Also, feel free to load up the page with an initial jpg of course!!!  i left the initial html setup blank on purpose.

Comment: this solution requires your page is w3 standards compliant. Specifically, no duplicate ID attributes!

Comment: +1 Good idea using objects to store references to the appropriate page.

Comment: @Defy Gravity, SIR, thank you very very much for your kindness...
SIR, kindly let me know how can I thank you...
Have a very good day and may GOD bless all...

Comment: @ Jonathan Sampson, SIR thank you very very much for your answer...
Kindly accept my kind wishes for you...
May God bless us all...

Answer (score 1):

#### Automatic file-name-based Replacement

Suppose you had a link like the following:

```
<a href="1.html" id="viewLarge">View Large</a>
```

That you wanted to dynamically change with each image. When image 2.jpg becomes the primary, we swap out 1.html for 2.html. We could modify the last line of your code to this:

```
// Updated Source of First Image
document.images[0].src = cImages[curImage];
// Parse Image Number from String
var currentNumber = parseInt( curImage, 10 ); // 2.jpg becomes 2
// Get a reference to our 'viewLarge' link
var ourLink = document.getElementById("viewLarge");
// 1.html becomes 2.html when 2 is the currentNumber;
ourLink.href = ourLink.href.replace( /^([0-9]+)/, currentNumber );
```

Note, though this works it restricts you to having a `1.html` for your `1.jpg`. This may be undesirable. You may want `1.jpg` to go with `CityLoft.html`. If that's the case, you'd want to associate the image with the proper url in your `cImages` object:

#### Use Objects to store Related Data

```
var cImages = [{image: '1.jpg', page: 'cityLoft.html'},
               {image: '2.jpg', page: 'townhome.html'}];
```

Once you've made this change, you only need to restore the references in your code. For instance, we would change the following:

```
document.images[0].src = cImages[curImage];
```

To this:

```
document.images[0].src = cImages[curImage].image;
```

We would also need to update our code that links to the relevant page as well:

```
document.getElementById("viewLarge").href = cImages[curImage].page;
```

That's it!